# How to passing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically I need to pass in the data variable but its not working

```
var data = 10

jQuery('#soundHandle').volumizer({passithere:[10,.0001]})
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you didn't pass the variable.

Comment: ive edit my question so you can understand

Comment: When you do this `{data:[10,.0001]}` you are creating a new object with a property called `data` that is not related to your variable.

Comment: @Connor you have to understand JSON string's structure: property & value.

Comment: Would you both like to go here and look at the second snippet down? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqery-html5-audio-file-fade-out because obviously you can do it, maybe you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var data = 10` is currently pointless. (It should also have a `;` on the end).

When you use object literal notation, `{data: []}` will just have a key set with the string `'data'`. If you really meant to set a key of whatever is in `data`, you would need to do something like:

```
passToVolumizer = {};
passToVolumizer[data] = [10, 0.0001];
jQuery('#soundHandle').volumizer(passToVolumizer);
```

But I suspect what you actually want to do is:

```
jQuery('#soundHandle').volumizer({data: [data, 0.001]});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myValue = 10;

jQuery('#soundHandle').volumizer({data:[myValue,.0001]})
```